# Creating play/pause functions with current audio javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension for chrome I am working on, I have an HTML popup that has buttons that play audio. I don't think my approach is the most elegant and I am having trouble exploring ways to shrink this down. I know this is very inefficient. I want to be able to tell which button was clicked on the HTML page, then using that ID play the audio file with that same ID. The way I have it now is using the EventListener in javascript to use multiple functions to stop or play. Is there a way to put all of this in one function through javascript or jquery to fix this chaos? **Since I am doing this on a chrome extension I cannot use Javascript in the HTML document.**

Currently I have my HTML like this;

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/audio.js"></script>

    <a href="#" class="myButton" id="stopbutton">Stop Audio</a> 
    <a href="#" class="myButton" id="aud1">Audio 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="myButton" id="aud2">Audio 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="myButton" id="aud3">Audio 3</a>
```

My JS file like this to create the variables for my audio files.

```
    var aud1 = new Audio();
    var aud2 = new Audio();
    var aud3 = new Audio();
```

Along with this function to start playback when a button is selected with the coresponding name.

```
    function aud1play() {
        aud1.src = "mp3/aud1.mp3";
        aud1.play();
    }
    document.getElementById('aud1').addEventListener('click', aud1play);

    //you get the trend
```

To stop my audio I have the following function:

```
    function audstop() {
        aud1.pause;
        aud2.pause;
        aud3.pause;
    document.getElementById('stopbutton').addEventListener('click', audstop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var audios= Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myButton"),function(el){
    var audio=new Audio();
    audio.preload="none";//=> not preloaded
    audio.src="mp3/"+el.id+".mp3";
    el.onclick=audio.play.bind(audio);
    return audio;
});
```

Simply iterate over your buttons, create an audio element with the right src for it, and bind the onclick listener to its play function. Then map the audio elements.

```
document.getElementById('stopbutton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    audios.forEach(audio=>audio.pause());
});
```

To stop, simply iterate over the audio elements and call the stop function on each...

Comment: Could you explain the Stop function a Little? How is it supposed to detect the current song?

Comment: @Collin Willson it simply stops all songs... ( it does the same as your stopfunction, however its a bit more DRY...)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. It does not work in testing, It says "audio.stop is not a function" in the console

Comment: I changed .stop to .pause and it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Collin Willson oh sorry for that typo... Youre welcome ;)

Comment: @Collin Willson and thats mainly because i load all audio elements on creation, so that they start on clicking the play button instantly...

Comment: @Jason w
I know this was a while ago, is there any way to make it load when the button is clicked as opposed to on page load? The long load time makes it difficult for my users. Thank you

Comment: @collin willson : have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement. Especially the *preload* property... ( you could set it to false)

Comment: @Jason w 
I looked into the documentation about the preload property. I am struggling with implementation. Would you be able to provide an example? Thank you.