# Optimizing audio preload from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making a soundboard Chrome extension that has buttons with a class of "myButtons". With that, I have my Javascript look for elements with that class, take their id and use that to make new audio instances off of their ID. 
**Chrome extensions have external js, must be in a js file not in the html document itself** The reason the extension loads so slow is that all 200+ audio files have to load before the popup for the extension appear. I don't know how to turn that preloading off to make my extension load quicker. The problem is that it takes up to 10 seconds to launch my extension with this. Which of course, is not at all ideal.

```
var audios = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myButton"), function (el) {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
el.onclick = audio.play.bind(audio);
return audio;
});
```

I have seen there is a preload property for audio instances (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement/1633059-preload), however, I am unsure how to implement this with my current function.

Comment: What are the `Content-Length` of the requested resources? If the file is requested before user clicks `el`, not certain how you are determining a ten second delay before audio playback begins?

Comment: I am not sure what that is.

Comment: What are the sizes of the requested audio files? Do you mean that when the element is clicked ten seconds elapse before audio playback begins?

Comment: Anywhere from .2 to 4mbs.  have done compression but that doesn't change loading speed

Comment: It takes ten seconds to load the entire extension. The audio file plays instantly.

Comment: Can you include "the entire extension" at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. How is entire extension related to `preload` attribute at `AudioNode`?

Comment: The reason the extension loads so slow is that all 200+ audio files have to load before the popup for the extension appear. I don't know how to turn that preloading off to make my extension load quicker.

Comment: Are you trying to load extension without all 200+ audio files being available for playback?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083628/creating-play-pause-functions-with-current-audio-javascript
I need them to load when clicked. So I can have the extension load instantly. I don't mind the time it takes to load the individual audio files.

Comment: There's also a declarative method: [audio.preload = 'none'](http://devdocs.io/html/element/audio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need them to load when clicked. So I can have the extension load
>   instantly. I don't mind the time it takes to load the individual audio
>   files.

Set `src` of `AudioNode` to URL pointing to media resource within `click` handler

```
var audios = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")
, function (el) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    var src = "mp3/" + el.id + ".mp3";
    el.onclick = function() {
                   audio.src = src;
                   audio.play();
                 };
    return audio;
});
```

Comment: Simple and wonderful, thank you. Would upvote if I had the Rep.